# The configuration section cannot contain a CDATA or text element

Tags: asp.net

I am working on a vb.net web application project. And I was stucked by the following error. I believe there is not syntax with my web.config. Please help me.

### Server Error in '/TSCA' Application.

Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The configuration section cannot contain a CDATA or text element.

Source Error:

Line 58:     -->
Line 59: 
Line 60:     
Line 61:            
Line 62:

Source File: C:\Users\310126745\Documents\TSCA\web.config    Line: 60

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929

Comment: Can you post what you have in your Web.config? Perhaps only the line 60.

Comment: Line 58: --> Line 59: Line 60: <authentication mode="Forms"> Line 61: <forms name="frmLogin" loginUrl="default.aspx" protection="All" path="/" timeout="60"/> Line 62: </authentication>  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but can't help. Do you have sensetive information in the Web.config or you can post it entirely?

Answer (score 0):

I hads same issue, You should resolve in two simple steps.

1) verify by opening the URL of the Web Service in the Web browser and make sure it is properly responding. (IMPORTANT)

2) If step 1 turned out well, sure there are no typos in the web.config since (happened to me) what can happen is you have been a character "<" or ">" or misspelled most.